# Is it possible to create MBtiles from a TIF?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, software-recommendations, mbtiles

I have a geo-referenced tif (it's really big around 1GB) and I'd like to convert it to mbtiles so I can serve them and view the map. What is the best tool to do this conversion?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. There are a lot of tools available (gdal2tiles, maptiler, mapnik), but you've asked for something subjective ("best") which makes it hard to provide an objective answer supported by references, and is hard to provide a useful answer since we don't know how to judge it - easy to use, easy to automate, accurate, flexible would all be reasonable measures, but unless you edit the question (just click edit below the question) to tell us what you really need to know.

Comment: Is the TIFF already paletted (or has RGB colors), or it contains raw pixel values (i.e. NDVI, height)?

Comment: A tool which was designed for converting GeoTIFF to MBTiles is MapTiler - see http://www.maptiler.com/.

Comment: See https://github.com/ecometrica/gdal2mbtiles or
https://github.com/mapbox/rio-mbtiles

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @BradHards comment - it would be best for you to let us know more details.

I'll assume you are new to the GIS space, and answer for ease of use.

Check out [Tilemill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) from mapbox.  It is easy to start with and will allow you to visually set up bounding box, zoom levels, starting zoom, etc. and then you can directly export to .mbtiles

Comment: I'd also recommend TileMill.  It's easy to work with, and if you get the dev build you can do some color manipulation on the tiff to sharpen/tint it, etc. if desired.  Here's a related tutorial that was helpful to me, and may be to you in some way... https://www.mapbox.com/blog/tilemill-raster-colorizer/